# Creating a popup box on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, popup

and thank you for viewing my post. I have a project in vb completed in Visual Studio 2010. Once the user clicks the submit button, I want a popup message that has certain text. I also want an okay and cancel button. If the user clicks okay, the page goes as normal and submits. It cancel is clicked, the page goes back for the user to edit info.

Now, I've tried using msgbox, but it doesn't work server side. From research, I found I prob need to use Jquery. I don't have much experience with that, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Josh

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        Me.btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Please note that what you have entered will be used to auto-generate the flyer. Also, submissions less than 30 days from the date entered may be denied.');")
    End If

    Dim objRequestID As Object = Nothing
    Dim intRequestID As Integer = 0

    Try
        If ValidateForm() Then
            Using objConnection As SqlConnection = util.GetConnection()
                Using objTransaction As SqlTransaction = objConnection.BeginTransaction
                    Using objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Request_Insert", objConnection)
                        With objCommand
                            .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                            .Transaction = objTransaction
                            .Parameters.Add("@CourseTypeID", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = util.CourseRequestType.PIE
                            .Parameters.Add("@SponsorName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = SponsorName.Text.Trim
                            .Parameters.Add("@SponsorPhone", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = SponsorPhone.Text.Trimenter code here
```

Comment: What have you tried to learn Jquery so far ? Where are you stucked ? What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I found source code, but don't understand how to code it in ASP.NET. do I need to create a new item, then make it run when a button is clicked?

Comment: It sounds like you need to start with some basic tutorials about web development, including the roles of various technologies (server-side code, client-side code, HTTP, etc.) which are involved in the process.  As your understanding of web development improves, you may come up with some ideas on how to structure something like this in your implementation, and then choose something like jQuery (which I would choose, but isn't the only option) as a tool to construct your solution.  If you're just looking for some code to copy/paste into your code, then this isn't really the place.

Comment: Well first of all help us understand exactly what you want by posting your source code

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to copy and paste. I understand that a popup control isn't available in ASP.net. Trying to find out ideas.

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021104-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, PhaDaPhunk. This link is very useful.

Comment: Okay, I've added code. I'm trying to manipulate what happens when the button is clicked. If you look at my main question, you'll see what I added. I didn't add everything, because it isn't relevant. The box is not showing up, and I'm sure you will prob see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `client button onclick` event at `server Page_Load` event.

When you reach to `btnSubmit_Click`, it is too late.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
      Me.btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Please...');")
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call this javascript on button click

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
  alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```